# ASP.NET Web API always returns 401 unauthorized error

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I am using Custom authorization on asp.net web api.I have followed the following link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/376810/ASP-NET-WEB-API-Custom-Authorize-and-Exception-Han
I use the attribute name in my controller like this

[mycustomattribute]

public class userController : apicontroller
{

}

but it always shows 401 unauthorized exception inspite of authentication status being authorized. I have followed exactly wat it is in the link for creating custom authorize attribute.

**my custom authorize class**

```
 public class tokenAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    DBEntity _objScrumDBEntities = new DBEntity ();
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("authenticationToken") != null)
        {
            // get value from header
            string authenticationTokenValue = Convert.ToString(actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("authenticationToken").FirstOrDefault());
            ObjectParameter m_tokenParam = new ObjectParameter("status", typeof(string));
            _objScrumDBEntities.validateToken(authenticationTokenValue, m_tokenParam);
           string status = Convert.IsDBNull(m_tokenParam.Value) ? null : (string)m_tokenParam.Value;
            if (status == "false")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("authenticationToken", authenticationTokenValue);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("AuthenticationStatus", "NotAuthorized");
                // actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                 return;
            }

            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("authenticationToken", authenticationTokenValue);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("AuthenticationStatus", "Authorized");                
                return;

            }
            //return;
        }
        //actionContext.Response =  actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
        //else
        // actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Please provide valid inputs";
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
[tokenAuthorize] 
public class myController : ApiController
{

    public IEnumerable<organization> Get()
    {
        return _objOrgRepository.GetAll();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share some code. This is too less for us to analyze

Comment: pls have a look at the code

Comment: You have the authenticationToken http header when you call the service right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(Username) does not get automatically hooked up when you have a custom AuthorizeAttribute and a custom RoleProvider.

So, in your custom AuthorizeAttribute you need to retrieve the list of roles from your data source and then compare them against the roles passed in as parameters to the AuthorizeAttribute.Try the below code

```
public class myController : ApiController

{

     [RequestKeyAuthorizeAttribute(Roles="Admin,Bob,Administrator,Clue")]
     public HttpResponseMessage Get()
     {
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "RequestKeyAuthorizeTestController");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Travis,But my aim is to authorize based on tokens that I receive from header and not route based on roles.But I inherited my customAuthorize class from "AuthorizationFilterAttribute" rather than "AuthorizeAttribute" and it works fine.